# Use AutoFixture to customize a collection

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

I have the following classes:

```
internal sealed class Report
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Usage> Usage { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class Usage
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to use AutoFixture, to create a collection of reports, each containing a set of `Usage` instances.

I would like to have at random between 15 and 30 usages (one for each date), in the last 30 days.

I tried using ICustomizations, ISpecimenBuilders, but I don't manage to create something workable.

What's the AutoFixture way of doing this?
I guess I need multiple ISpecimenBuilders to perform what I would like to do.

Another option would be to use 1 ISpecimenBuilder with a Random and use that one to control everything (to generate dates, counts, ...)

Be aware that this is a sample, and that the actual object graph which I would like to construct is larger.

To give a bit of context, the classes are representing entities in my DB, and I would like to fill the DB before my tests are being executed.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to have at random between 15 and 30 usages (one for each date), in the last 30 days.

It sounds like you have a pretty good idea of what you need your data to look like for the purpose of your test.

In my experience, the primary value of AutoFixture is to create the values you *don't* care about, so that your test code can focus on the things you *do* care about. If you want to create random dates between specific values, etc., write code to do that for you. Just use AutoFixture to create things like the `Name`, which your test doesn't care about.

```
var reports = fixture.Build<Report>().Without(r => r.Usage).CreateMany().ToList();
foreach (var report in reports)
{
    // "(one for each date), in the last 30 days"
    var possibleDates = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i)).ToList();
    // "at random between 15 and 30 usages"
    var numberOfUsages = Random.Shared.Next(15, 30); // should 30 be inclusive or exclusive?
    var randomlyChosenDates = possibleDates.OrderBy(_ => Random.Shared.Next()).Take(numberOfUsages).ToList();
    report.Usage = randomlyChosenDates
        .Select(d => new Usage 
        {
            DateTime = d,
            Count = fixture.Create<int>() // or however you want to determine the Count
        })
        .ToList();
}
```